# How to pass Dynamic textbox values that is created by Javascript to controller in MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to pass Dynamic textbox values  that is created by Javascript to controller in MVC?

On my view I have this part where I add textbox dynamically, I want to get the values from the textboxes on POST on controller:

```
  <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">

        <label>Textbox #1 : </label>@Html.TextBox("textbox1") &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Just put a name attribute on your textboxes and just make sure it matches your MVC action parameters so it will be binded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using FormCollection you can get the value and you need to put name attribute

```
public ActionResult GetFormData(FormCollection form)
{
    string value= form["your Input name"].ToString();
    retun View();
}
```

Comment: additionaly since you may have multiple textboxes created dynamically maybe add a hidden field in the view which will contain the value of number of textboxes. This way you can loop through some predefined naming convention of textboxes.